# Angular Testing Pipe that depends on Pipe (inject() must be called from an injection context)

Tags: angular, ts-jest, angular-test

I'm having trouble with a test in Angular (using jest) for a pipe that depends on the `DatePipe`.  The error I'm getting is:

```
NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor,
a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with `runInInjectionContext`.
Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0203
```

But it is complaining about a field initializer:

[image]

This is my pipe:

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldValue, Timestamp } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timestampDate',
  standalone: true,
})
export class TimestampDatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  private readonly _datePipe = inject(DatePipe);

  transform(
    timestamp: FieldValue | Timestamp | undefined | null
  ): string | null {
    if (!timestamp) return '...';
    if (timestamp instanceof Timestamp)
      return this._datePipe.transform(timestamp.toDate(), 'short');
    else throw new Error('Timestamp must be an instance of Timestamp');
  }
}
```

And this is my spec:

```js
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { TimestampDatePipe } from './timestamp-date.pipe';

describe('TimestampDatePipe', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [DatePipe],
    });
  });

  it('create an instance', () => {
    const pipe = new TimestampDatePipe();
    expect(pipe).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have the rudimentary understanding that I can use the `inject` function during what I call "constructor time."  This is what I'm doing because it is being used in a field initializer, which the error is telling me to do.  Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

## note

I'm not sure its worth mentioning, but this pipe is located in a separate library in a nx workspace.

## update

If I use DI via the constructor parameter for the DatePipe, and construct my outer pipe, in the test, with

```js
const pipe = new TimestampDatePipe(TestBed.inject(DatePipe));
```

the error seems to go away.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, when you instantiate your pipe manually you're not in an [injection context](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-context).

To fix the issue you can ask the TestBed to create the pipe for you :

```
const pipe = TestBed.inject(TimestampDatePipe)
```

Comment: Interesting.  I got the "constructor-time" confused with "injection-context" and was treated them the same.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

The right way to fix this would be to use `runInInjectionContext`:

```
let pipe;

TestBed.runInInjectionContext(() => {
  pipe = new TimestampDatePipe();
});
```